# Projeto Pesquisar PHP

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho as seguintes linhas de um Projeto de Busca usando o metodo GET estou tentando implementar um segundo campo no INPUT mais sem sucesso :(

Alguem por favor me ajuda a inserir um novo campo para que a busca seja feita em 2 colunas ai mesmo tempo?

Este é o codigo

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);?>
<?php include_once("conexao.php");
//Verificar se está sendo passado na URL a página atual, senao é atribuido a pagina 
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
if(!isset($_GET['pesquisar']) && ($_GET['pesquisar1']) ) 
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $valor_pesquisar = $_GET['pesquisar'];  
}

//Selecionar todos os cursos da tabela
$result_curso = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nome  LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' AND conteudo LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar1%' ";
$resultado_curso = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curso);

//Contar o total de cursos
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curso);

//Seta a quantidade de cursos por pagina
$quantidade_pg = 6;

//calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os cursos
$num_pagina = ceil($total_cursos/$quantidade_pg);

//Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
$incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;



//Todas as Mensagens

    $result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' AND conteudo LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar1%'";
    $resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn , $result_cursos);



//Contar o total de itens
    $total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cursos);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Criar pagina com abas</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
            <div class="page-header">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">
                <span class="badge"><?php echo $total_cursos; ?></span> encontrados em <b><?php echo $valor_pesquisar; ?></b>
            </button>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <h1>Cursos</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="pesquisar.php">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputName2">Pesquisar</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pesquisar" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Digitar...">
                                <input type="text" name="pesquisar1" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Digitarddd...">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <?php

            $total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cursos);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cursos) <= 0){
                        echo '<div class="alert alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                              <strong>Ops!</strong> Não encontramos oque procurava, tente denovo!
                              </div>';
                        }
            ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cursos)){ ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="imagens/produto.jpg" alt="...">
                            <div class="caption text-center">
                                <a href="detalhes.php?id_curso=<?php echo $rows_cursos['id']; ?>"><h3><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome']; ?></h3></a>
                                <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Comprar</a> </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
}, 2500);                                       
    </script>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seja mais claro em sua pergunta e restrinja o código ao conteúdo relevante a um [MCVE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wesley,

Você esta usando no form um **GET** que é um método de enviar um formulário que é mais rápido que o post porem tem a visibilidade pelo navegador, caso não queira que ninguém veja utilize post porem a resposta é um pouco mais demorada devido seu encapsulamento.

- Para utilizar o **GET** e só você declarar o $_GET['nome do "NAME"'].

Uma dica de ouro não utilize o like na sua procedure pois e mais lento. nessa situação eu usaria assim:

- "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE nome = "$_GET[pesquisar]" AND conteudo =
  "$_GET[pesquisar1]"

Pois assim seria mais simples, rápido a sua consulta e não pesaria ao banco de dados.

Comment: Dessa forma esta dando erro na linha do SELECT

Comment: Faltou concatenar os `$_GET` e colocar aspas pois são strings

Comment: ainda não consegui, pelo meu código aqui parece que ele não esta conseguindo buscar pelo conteudo, por exemplo quero que faça uma busca no pesquisar e pesquisar1 e retorne somente os resultados que tenha os termos pesquisados..

Comment: manda o erro por aqui

Comment: compara com um codigo meu

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                while ($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
                
                {
                  echo 
                  "$linha[nome_produto]"}

Comment: meu select fiz assim                                                                                                              
    $user =  $_POST['usuario'];
    $pass = $_POST['senha'];

    $query = "SELECT nome_usuario, usuario_usuario, senha_usuario, acesso_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_usuario = '$user' AND senha_usuario = '$pass'";

Comment: Você esta testando as procedures no banco de dados  ? qual erro da no banco de dados ?,  e qual erro apresenta no php ?

Comment: quando não apresenta na tela erro no php é erro no banco de dados eu para gerenciar meu mysql eu uso heidisql

Comment: Consegui usando sua dica e mudando alguns parametros.  valeuuuu

Answer (score 2):

Wesley Roberto, você não esta atribuindo o valor para variável de valor_pesquisa1

}else{

```
$valor_pesquisar = $_GET['pesquisar'];  

$valor_pesquisar1 = $_GET['pesquisar1'];
```

}

Comment: Você esta passando somente um dos inputs do form e é necessário os dois.

Comment: como eu faço isso ??

Comment: da forma que ele mostrou acima ué, basta adicionar uma nova variavel e usar um novo $_get para pegar o valor do input!

Comment: Sim acabei de fazer porem não está funcionando, ele até grava o termo da segunda input porem não retorna o resultado, ex se eu buscar por Wesley (pesquisar) e Roberto na (pesquisar1), ele só apresenta os resultados Wesley. entende?

Comment: ou seja mesmo que exista 10 resultados por Wesley ele só vai retornar como resposta somente os que São Wesley Roberto.

Comment: @WesleyRoberto mas não é isso que você quer? Apenas os registros que são Wesley e Roberto ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Não, quero que ele busque Wesley na coluna NOME e na Coluna SOBRENOME (que no meu projeto está como conteudo) Roberto. 
e só vai me apresentar como resultado os nomes que forme Wesley Roberto, entendeu?

Comment: @WesleyRoberto entendi agora.